Iterating the Dedekind cut construction
Let's call a dense, linearly ordered set with no maximum and minimum elements a line.
Given a line $L$, consider the collection $\mathcal{D}(L)$ of Dedekind cuts of $L$. Then $\mathcal{D}(L)$ is also a line.
Call $L$ Dedekind-complete if $\mathcal{D}(L)\cong L$.
Questions:

Is it always true that for any line $L$, $\mathcal{D}(L)$ is Dedekind-complete?
Suppose that $L$ is an ordered abelian group that forms a line, and it is also a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space in a way that respects the order of $L$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. If $L$ is Dedekind complete, must $L\cong\mathbb{R}$?


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion
